# Finding equally spaced points of given Konva.Line

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, konvajs

I have created a Konva.Line and would like to draw a Star at equal intervals along this line. Not that it matters but the line is rarely straight. As an alternative, I have a list of points {x,y} that define the line and rather than creating the Konva.Line, I could draw the equally spaced stars along the list of Points which are not equally spaced.

Here is the function I have so far. It does draw the stars but they do not end up equally spaced.

```
this.lastPointerPosition = this.stage.getPointerPosition();
this.mouseDownCache.push({x: this.lastPointerPosition.x, y: this.lastPointerPosition.y});
let i = 0;
let interval = this.parent.scaleValue / 2;
let currentTravel = 0;
let storedSegments = 0;
let point = {};

for(let p of this.mouseDownCache){
  if(i > 0){
    let startx = numeral(this.mouseDownCache[i-1].x).value();
    let starty = numeral(this.mouseDownCache[i-1].y).value();
    let endx = numeral(p.x).value();
    let endy = numeral(p.y).value();
    let segmentLength = (Math.sqrt((startx - endx) * (startx - endx) + (starty - endy) * (starty - endy)));
    currentTravel += segmentLength;
    if(currentTravel >= interval){
      let n = Math.floor(currentTravel / interval);
      let offsetlength = interval - storedSegments;
      let xlen = endx - startx;
      let ylen = endy - starty;
      let hlen = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xlen,2) + Math.pow(ylen,2));
      let ratio = offsetlength / hlen;
      let smallerXLen = xlen * ratio;
      let smallerYLen = ylen * ratio;
      for(let s=0;s<n;s++){
        let fromx = startx, fromy = starty;
        if(s > 0){
          fromx = point.x; fromy = point.y;
          xlen = endx - point.x;
          ylen = endy - point.y;
          hlen = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xlen,2) + Math.pow(ylen,2));
          if(hlen > 0){
            ratio = interval / hlen;
            smallerXLen = xlen * ratio;
            smallerYLen = ylen * ratio;
            point = {x: fromx+smallerXLen, y: fromy+smallerYLen};
            this.drawStarAtPoint(this.layer, point);
          }
        }else{
          point = {x: fromx+smallerXLen, y: fromy+smallerYLen};
          this.drawStarAtPoint(this.layer, point);
        }
      }
      currentTravel = (Math.sqrt((point.x - endx) * (point.x - endx) + (point.y - endy) * (point.y - endy)));
      storedSegments = 0;
    }else{
      storedSegments += segmentLength;
    }
  }
  i++
}
this.layer.draw();
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I updated the question to include the function that I currently have.